# Backup iPhoto images using non-incremental backups

Tags: macos, mac, sync, iphoto

I have my MacBook backing up to a Time Machine drive and that is working nicely.

I also have a Network Storage Drive (ReadyNas NV+) on my home network and I would really like to be able to copy all the photos from my iPhoto library to it on a regular basis.

My main objective is to be able to access images from my iPhoto library from other computers on my home network.

Any ideas? I really don't know what tools are out there for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to just copy the whole iPhoto library  (~/Pictures/iPhoto Library) over to the other machine (and replace the iPhoto library there).

Merging would be difficult, but if you just want to use it as is (replace the whole library on a regular basis with the latest one), that works. Just don't start editing stuff or adding pictures in the copied library, as those changes will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using rsync which comes bundled with OS X to sync your iPhoto library to the NAS. There is even a great GUI frontend available called [rsyncx](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/16814) to make your life a whole lot easier:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about the sharing feature built into iPhoto? Preferences --> Sharing --> Share my photos. On other computers you will need the option `Look for shared photos` to be turned on, which it should be by default.

You can choose to share all or selected albums, and it can be password protected.

Comment: The problem with this is that the host computer needs to be turned on, the user needs to be logged in, and have iPhoto running.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions are:

- simple copy
- rsync with terminal or GUI
- [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/)